# Entropic force in rubber bands

Tags: entropy

The formulation for entropic force of stretching a rubber band is now known. Are there any other such daily life examples that also have mathematical formulations of entropic forces associated with them? Or can the idea and theory be extrapolated in such a way that more physical phenomena can be explained by it?

Comment: The [Entropic Force Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_force) seems to give a few: can you say what further you might want to find out about these examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy example of another entropic force would be that exerted by, say, a box of ideal gas with a wall that can move in or out.  Push on this movable wall and you increase the pressure of this gas.  Conversely, the force which would try to reduce the pressure by moving the wall outwards is "entropic" in the same sense as the force which seeks to contract a stretched rubber band.

Comment: Ah. Can this idea be extrapolated further? Pistons, squeezing a sponge and so on?

Comment: Yep,those forces also arise from entropy maximization at finite temperature.